# Access denied error while runnig Redshift COPY command using Temp credential

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, access-denied

I am trying to run the Redshift COPY command using the temporary credentials (reading it from instance metadata).
The role that is assigned to my EC2 instance for s3 resource is having below access

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:PutObject*",
        "s3:DeleteObject*"
],
```

but when I run the app I am getting

> ERROR: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied.

As per the documentation the a/c should have LIST and GET access to S3 bucket which I have given in this case.

Why is this failing?

Comment: i tired with giving full s3 permission to the role that the EC2 instance is running with and still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

When using temporary credentials, it is not enough to use the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. You should also be using the token that comes with them. For more information read:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_copy-temporary-security-credentials.html

Comment: the issue is not with the credentials. Ia m passing the token as part of credentials.

Comment: also, are you giving access permissions to the objects inside the bucket then?

Comment: What permissions? Do i need to make the objects public?

Comment: let's say we have a bucket named mybucket. You need to add permissions to the bucket itself mybucket: {read...} and to the bucket contents mybucket/*: {read....}